# password confirmation is not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have to give a registration facility to a store. There the user have to enter name, password,confirm password. But when I am trying to enter a different password for confirmation, it isn't showing any error and user is successfully getting registered. 
Here is the code in UserMOdel

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
       validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
       validates :password, :presence =>true,  :confirmation =>true
       validates_confirmation_of :password
       has_secure_password 
     end
```

And my code in views/users/_form.html.erb is as follows..

```
 <div class="depot_form">
       <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being    saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

     <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter User Details</legend>
        <div >
     <%= f.label :name %>:
       <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40 %>
      </div>
       <div>
       <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>:
       <%= f.password_field :password, :size => 40 %>
       </div>
       <div>
       <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password' %>:
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :size => 40 %>
       </div>
      <div>
         <%= f.submit %>
          </div>
       </fieldset>

     <% end %>

     </div>
```

I have gone through various solutions and modifications, but in vain...
Any help please..

Comment: More important than seeing your view is seeing your controller code here.

Answer (score 5):

Add this validation too:

```
   validates :password_confirmation, :presence =>true
```

A presence check is still required for confirmation attribute.

Read - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You should use devise gem for this use case.

and for devise use this attributes

```
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable,
 :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

To read more about Devise Click [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)